# Intersection / union for each set of words in any given two lists python in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, set

I'm trying to define Score as the intersection / union for each set of words in any given two lists. I understand that union and intersections are only available for set type of container and I've struggled so bad to be able to set it right but haven't been able to, could someone please help?

```
corpus = [
    ["i","did","not","like","the","service"],
    ["the","service","was","ok"],
    ["i","was","ignored","when","i","asked","for","service"]
]
tags = ["a","b","c"]
dct_keys = {
    "a":1,
    "b":2,
    "c":3
}
corpus_tags = dict(zip(tags,corpus))

from itertools import combinations
my_keys = list(combinations(tags, 2))

goal_dct = {}
for i in range(len(my_keys)):
    goal_dct[(my_keys[i])] = {"id_alpha":(dct_keys[my_keys[i][0]]),
                             "id_beta"  :(dct_keys[my_keys[i][1]]),
                             "socore" : (len(set1&set3))/(len(set1|set3))} # THIS IS WHAT I WAS TRYING TO ACHIEVE HERE
print(goal_dct)
```

This is what I was trying to define as score, to set the example:

```
set1 = {"i","did","not","like","the","service"}
set2 = {"the","service","was","ok"}
set3 = {"i","was","ignored","when","i","asked","for","service"}
(len(set1&set3))/(len(set1|set3))
```

Comment: What are you trying to with the `&` and `|` operators?  I don't understand how bitwise operations would apply here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
(len(set1)&len(set3))/(len(set1)|len(set3))
```

`len` returns an `int`.  You can use the `&` and `|` operators on ints, but it does bitwise operations, which is not what you're looking for.  Instead, you want to use those operators on the *sets*, and then take the `len` of those resulting sets:

```
len(set1 & set3)/len(set1 | set3)
```

So a function that produces the score for any two lists of strings (sentences) would look like:

```
def score(s1: list[str], s2: list[str]) -> float:
    set1, set2 = set(s1), set(s2)
    return len(set1 & set2) / len(set1 | set2)
```

and you can use this to build scores for all the combinations in `corpus`:

```
from itertools import combinations
from string import ascii_lowercase

corpus = [
    ["i","did","not","like","the","service"],
    ["the","service","was","ok"],
    ["i","was","ignored","when","i","asked","for","service"]
]
tagged_corpus = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, corpus))

def score(s1: list[str], s2: list[str]) -> float:
    set1, set2 = set(s1), set(s2)
    return len(set1 & set2) / len(set1 | set2)

goal = {
    (a, b): score(tagged_corpus[a], tagged_corpus[b])
    for a, b in combinations(tagged_corpus, 2)
}

print(goal)  
# ('a', 'b'): 0.25, 
# ('a', 'c'): 0.18181818181818182, 
# ('b', 'c'): 0.2222222222222222}
```

Comment: Ok get it and I'll change the scheme, but do you have any idea on how to select each sentence corresponding to each pair of tags to build score?

Comment: Do you want a score for each possible two-sentence permutation in `corpus`?

Comment: regarding each goal_dct key pair of tags accordingly

Comment: Do you really need to have two different identifiers for each sentence in the corpus?  It all seems really unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Agree with you Samwise but there's a structure I must follow. Thank you so much for your answer & patience here!

Answer (score 0):

Make sets from your lists.

```
set1 = set(some_list)
set2 = set(other_list)
common_items = set1.intersection(set2)
```

Comment: Yeah sure but I'm trying to define it in the same function as I set the example above

Comment: @MelaniaCB I don't understand the problem.  If you can't use this solution, please explain _why_.

Comment: My problem is selecting which pair of sentences to build score from inside that for loop. Am I being clear?

Comment: @MelaniaCB Ah, so now your question is not about sets.  Got it.